# IP sorting program

Tags: java, sorting, ip-address

The purpose of this little program is to:

- Separate `IPv4 addresses` and `IPv6 addresses`
- Will be able to sort them even if the formatting of the input is not great
- Sort them into an order
- Print them into the system terminal in ascending and descending order

I would like to know if you think the program what it is meant to do properly. I would particularly be interested in your thoughts on the efficiency of the program and if any improvements can be made to it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class IPSort
{
    String[] tests = {":8:","::::5:6::8","::::5:6::7","::::5:6::8","123..245.23","1...","..1.","123...23",".1..","123..245.23", "123..245.23", "104.244.253.29", "1.198.3.93", "32.183.93.40", "32.183.93.40", "104.30.244.2", "104.244.4.1","0.0.0.1",":a:","::5:3:4:5:6:78","1::2:3","1::2:3:4","1::5:256.2.3.4","1:1:3000.30.30.30","ae80::217:f2ff:254:7:237:98"};
    ArrayList<String> bit32 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> bit128 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> cleanBit32 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> cleanBit128 = new ArrayList<String>();

    boolean myMatcher32Bit(String s)
    {
        Pattern patter32Bit = Pattern.compile("^(?=(?:[^.]*\\.){3}[^.]*$)(?=(?:[^:]*:){0}[^:]*$)(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[^a-zA-Z])*$)");
        Matcher matcher32Bit = patter32Bit.matcher(s);
        return matcher32Bit.find();
    }

    boolean myMatcher128Bit(String s)
    {
        Pattern patter128Bit = Pattern.compile("^(?=(?:[^.]*\\.){0}[^.]*$)(?=(?:[^:]*:){1,7}[^:]*$)");
        Matcher matcher128Bit = patter128Bit.matcher(s);
        return matcher128Bit.find();
    }

    public void sortIntoRespectiveIPTypes()
    {
        for(String s: tests)
        {
            if(myMatcher32Bit(s))
            {
                bit32.add(s);
            }
            else if(myMatcher128Bit(s))
            {
                bit128.add(s);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("32 bit IPs");
        for(String ip: bit32)
        {
            System.out.println("  "+ip);
        }

        System.out.println("\n128 bit IPs");
        for(String ip: bit128)
        {
            System.out.println("  "+ip);
        }

        int count = 0;
        for(String ip: tests)
        {
            if(myMatcher32Bit(ip)==false && myMatcher128Bit(ip)==false)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if(count != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nDidn't match an IP format");
            for(String ip: tests)
            {
                if(myMatcher32Bit(ip)==false && myMatcher128Bit(ip)==false)
                {
                    System.out.println("  "+ip);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void sort32BitIPs(ArrayList<String> bit32, ArrayList<String> newBit32)
    {
        ArrayList<BigInteger> bigInt32Bit = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        for(String ip:bit32)
        {
            String[] tempArray = ip.split("\\.");
            int i=0;
            for(String s:tempArray)
            {
                if(s.equals(""))
                {
                    tempArray[i]="0";
                }
                i++;
            }
            bigInt32Bit.add(convert32Bit(tempArray));
        }

        Collections.sort(bigInt32Bit);

        ArrayList<String> fixFormat = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String ip:bit32)
        {
            String[] fixArray = ip.split("\\.");
            int i=0;
            for(String s:fixArray)
            {
                if(s.equals(""))
                {
                    fixArray[i]="0";
                }
                i++;
            }

            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 4; i2++) 
            {
                if(i2<3)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if(!fixArray[i2].equals(""))
                        {
                            strBuilder.append(fixArray[i2]+".");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strBuilder.append(".");
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        strBuilder.append("0.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        strBuilder.append(fixArray[i2]);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        strBuilder.append("0");
                    }
                }
            }
            String newString = strBuilder.toString();
            fixFormat.add(newString);
            bit32=fixFormat;
        }

        for(BigInteger finalValue:bigInt32Bit)
        {
            for(String ip:bit32)
            {
                String[] tempArray = ip.split("\\.");
                int i=0;
                for(String s:tempArray)
                {
                    if(s.equals(""))
                    {
                        tempArray[i]="0";
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if(finalValue.equals(convert32Bit(tempArray)))
                {
                    if(!newBit32.contains(ip))
                    {
                        String str = bit32.toString();
                        String findStr = ip;
                        int lastIndex = 0;
                        int count = 0;

                        while(lastIndex != -1){

                            lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);

                            if(lastIndex != -1){
                                count++;
                                lastIndex += findStr.length();
                            }
                        }

                        for(int k = 0; k<count;k++)
                        {
                            newBit32.add(ip);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    BigInteger convert32Bit(String[] array)
    {
        int[] tempArray = new int[array.length];
        ArrayList<BigInteger> tempBigIntList = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        int i = 0;
        for(String s:array)
        {
            int power = 4-i;
            tempArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(s);
            String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[i]);
            BigInteger myBigInt = new BigInteger(string);
            BigInteger num2 = myBigInt.multiply(new BigInteger("256").pow(power));
            tempBigIntList.add(num2);
            i++;
        }
        BigInteger bigInt32Bit = new BigInteger("0");
        for(BigInteger bI:tempBigIntList)
        {
            bigInt32Bit = bigInt32Bit.add(bI);
        }
        return bigInt32Bit;
    }

    public void sort128BitIPs(ArrayList<String> bit128,ArrayList<String> newBit128)
    {
        ArrayList<BigInteger> bigInt128Bit = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        for(String ip:bit128)
        {
            String[] tempArray = ip.split(":");
            int i=0;
            for(String s:tempArray)
            {
                if(s.equals(""))
                {
                    tempArray[i]="0";
                }
                i++;
            }
            bigInt128Bit.add(convert128Bit(tempArray));
        }

        Collections.sort(bigInt128Bit);

        for(BigInteger finalValue:bigInt128Bit)
        {
            for(String ip:bit128)
            {
                String[] tempArray = ip.split(":");
                int i=0;
                for(String s:tempArray)
                {
                    if(s.equals(""))
                    {
                        tempArray[i]="0";
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if(finalValue.equals(convert128Bit(tempArray)))
                {
                    if(!newBit128.contains(ip))
                    {
                        String str = bit128.toString();
                        String findStr = ip;
                        int lastIndex = 0;
                        int count = 0;

                        while(lastIndex != -1){

                            lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);

                            if(lastIndex != -1){
                                count++;
                                lastIndex += findStr.length();
                            }
                        }

                        for(int k = 0; k<count;k++)
                        {
                            newBit128.add(ip);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    BigInteger convert128Bit(String[] array)
    {
        int[] tempArray = new int[array.length];
        ArrayList<BigInteger> tempBigIntList = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        int i = 0;
        for(String s:array)
        {
            int power = 8-i;
            tempArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(s,16);
            String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[i]);
            BigInteger myBigInt = new BigInteger(string);
            BigInteger num2 = myBigInt.multiply(new BigInteger("65536").pow(power));
            tempBigIntList.add(num2);
            i++;
        }
        BigInteger bigInt128Bit = new BigInteger("0");
        for(BigInteger bI:tempBigIntList)
        {
            bigInt128Bit = bigInt128Bit.add(bI);
        }
        return bigInt128Bit;
    }

    public void printInOrder(ArrayList<String> bit32,ArrayList<String> bit128)
    {
        System.out.println("\nSorted IPs");

        System.out.println("Sorted 32 bit IPs - Ascending");
        for(String ip: bit32)
        {
            System.out.println("  "+ip);
        }

        Collections.reverse(bit32);
        System.out.println("\nSorted 32 bit IPs - Descending");
        for(String ip: bit32)
        {
            System.out.println("  "+ip);
        }

        System.out.println("\nSorted 128 bit IPs - Ascending");
        for(String ip: bit128)
        {
            System.out.println("  "+ip);
        }

        Collections.reverse(bit128);
        System.out.println("\nSorted 128 bit IPs - Descending");
        for(String ip: bit128)
        {
            System.out.println("  "+ip);
        }
    }

    public void run(ArrayList<String> bit32,ArrayList<String> bit128,ArrayList<String> newBit32,ArrayList<String> newBit128)
    {
        sortIntoRespectiveIPTypes();
        sort32BitIPs(bit32,newBit32);
        sort128BitIPs(bit128,newBit128);
        printInOrder(newBit32,newBit128);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IPSort ipS = new IPSort();
        ipS.run(ipS.bit32,ipS.bit128,ipS.cleanBit32,ipS.cleanBit128);
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Any other comments, tips or suggestions are welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered treating IPv4 addresses as [IPv4-mapped addresses](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2765#section-2.1) and sorting all of the addresses in the same IPv6 address space?

Comment: Many of the 128-bit IP addresses in your test are actually invalid according to [RFC 4291 Sec 2.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.2): "The preferred form is x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x, where the 'x's are **one** to four hexadecimal digits" — not zero to four. Zeroes can be compressed, but only using a double colon.

Comment: @200_success Thank you for the information I shall look into these things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel, and doing it incorrectly.

Java already has a `java.net.InetAddress` class to represent IP addresses, with subclasses `Inet4Address` and `Inet6Address`.  You can parse addresses using `InetAddress.getByName(…)`.

Your IPv6 parsing is wrong.  Don't assume that IPv6 addresses behave like IPv4 addresses with colons instead of dots and hexadecimal instead of decimal numbers; read [RFC2765 Sec 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2765#section-2.1) for the specification.  In particular, most of the addresses you had in your example are actually invalid IPv6 addresses.  A double-colon in an IPv6 address expands to as many zeros as necessary to fill the 128 bits; there can be at most one double-colon in an address.

Once you have a class to represent IP addresses (whether using the standard `InetAddress` or one of your own invention), a good way to sort them is to define a `Comparator`.  It's much cleaner to sort objects using the right comparator than to try to parse strings into a `BigInteger` representation, sort the addresses as numbers, and reformat the results as strings.

In the demonstration below, I have used Java 8 streams for convenience.  The result is substantially shorter than your original code, and more standards-compliant.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.Inet6Address;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class IPSort {
    private static String[] TESTS = { … };

    /**
     * Comparator for InetAddresses.  IPv4 are compared to IPv6
     * addresses by converting IPv4 addresses to IPv4-compatible
     * IPv6 addresses according to RFC2765 Sec 2.1.
     */
    public static class InetAddressComparator implements Comparator<InetAddress> {
        @Override
        public int compare(InetAddress a, InetAddress b) {
            byte[] aOctets = a.getAddress(),
                   bOctets = b.getAddress();
            int len = Math.max(aOctets.length, bOctets.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                byte aOctet = (i >= len - aOctets.length) ?
                    aOctets[i - (len - aOctets.length)] : 0;
                byte bOctet = (i >= len - bOctets.length) ?
                    bOctets[i - (len - bOctets.length)] : 0;
                // Unsigned byte comparison (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19186)
                if (aOctet != bOctet) return (0xff & aOctet) - (0xff & bOctet);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static Optional<InetAddress> toInetAddress(String s) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(InetAddress.getByName(s));
        } catch (UnknownHostException badAddress) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Valid 32-bit addresses");
        Arrays.stream(TESTS)
              .map(IPSort::toInetAddress)
              .filter(Optional::isPresent)
              .map(Optional::get)
              .filter((addr) -> addr instanceof Inet4Address)
              .map(InetAddress::getHostAddress)
              .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("\nValid 128-bit addresses");
        Arrays.stream(TESTS)
              .map(IPSort::toInetAddress)
              .filter(Optional::isPresent)
              .map(Optional::get)
              .filter((addr) -> addr instanceof Inet6Address)
              .map(InetAddress::getHostAddress)
              .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("\nInvalid addresses");
        Arrays.stream(TESTS)
              .filter((s) -> !toInetAddress(s).isPresent())
              .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("\nSorted addresses");
        Arrays.stream(TESTS)
              .map(IPSort::toInetAddress)
              .filter(Optional::isPresent)
              .map(Optional::get)
              .sorted(new InetAddressComparator())
              .map(InetAddress::getHostAddress)
              .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("\nReverse-sorted 32-bit addresses");
        Arrays.stream(TESTS)
              .map(IPSort::toInetAddress)
              .filter(Optional::isPresent)
              .map(Optional::get)
              .filter((addr) -> addr instanceof Inet4Address)
              .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(new InetAddressComparator()))
              .map(InetAddress::getHostAddress)
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Import Statements

Before I start complaining about your import statements, I want you to know that the package declaration `import java.lang.*` is implied in all Java programs and is not necessary.

---

*Never* import the whole package. *Always* import only what you need. So in the case of your import statements:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
```

It would be:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Looks a lot more organized, and you see exactly what you need.

### Formatting

I see some formatting issues in your code. In method declarations:

```
public void sort128BitIPs(ArrayList<String> bit128,ArrayList<String> newBit128)
```

Parameters should be separated with a comma followed by a space, not just a comma. You do this once, but just once.

---

Here:

```
        tempArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(s);
```

There should be always spaces before and after an operator, not just `=`. In your code, you also have the same problem with `+`.

---

About your bracing style, you mostly have the braces on a new line, but here:

```
                    while(lastIndex != -1){

                        lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);

                        if(lastIndex != -1){
                            count++;
                            lastIndex += findStr.length();
                        }
                    }
```

You don't.

Choose a style, and stick to it. I suggest the brace on the same line, as that is what the standard Java conventions recommend, but it's your choice.

### List declarations

Instead of declaring an `ArrayList` as an `ArrayList`, it is better practice to declare it to just `List`. Here:

```
ArrayList<String> bit32 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> bit128 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> cleanBit32 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> cleanBit128 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Should be:

```
List<String> bit32 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> bit128 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> cleanBit32 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> cleanBit128 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And this:

```
public void run(ArrayList<String> bit32,ArrayList<String> bit128,ArrayList<String> newBit32,ArrayList<String> newBit128)
{
    sortIntoRespectiveIPTypes();
    sort32BitIPs(bit32,newBit32);
    sort128BitIPs(bit128,newBit128);
    printInOrder(newBit32,newBit128);
}
```

Turns into:

```
public void run(List<String> bit32, List<String> bit128, List<String> newBit32, List<String> newBit128)
{
    sortIntoRespectiveIPTypes();
    sort32BitIPs(bit32,newBit32);
    sort128BitIPs(bit128,newBit128);
    printInOrder(newBit32,newBit128);
}
```

And everywhere else you declare them as `ArrayList`s, change it into `List`.

The code so far:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class IPSort {

    String[] tests = { ":8:", "::::5:6::8", "::::5:6::7", "::::5:6::8",
            "123..245.23", "1...", "..1.", "123...23", ".1..", "123..245.23",
            "123..245.23", "104.244.253.29", "1.198.3.93", "32.183.93.40",
            "32.183.93.40", "104.30.244.2", "104.244.4.1", "0.0.0.1", ":a:",
            "::5:3:4:5:6:78", "1::2:3", "1::2:3:4", "1::5:256.2.3.4",
            "1:1:3000.30.30.30", "ae80::217:f2ff:254:7:237:98" };
    List<String> bit32 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> bit128 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> cleanBit32 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> cleanBit128 = new ArrayList<String>();

    boolean myMatcher32Bit(String s) {
        Pattern patter32Bit = Pattern.compile(
                "^(?=(?:[^.]*\\.){3}[^.]*$)(?=(?:[^:]*:){0}[^:]*$)(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[^a-zA-Z])*$)");
        Matcher matcher32Bit = patter32Bit.matcher(s);
        return matcher32Bit.find();
    }

    boolean myMatcher128Bit(String s) {
        Pattern patter128Bit = Pattern.compile(
                "^(?=(?:[^.]*\\.){0}[^.]*$)(?=(?:[^:]*:){1,7}[^:]*$)");
        Matcher matcher128Bit = patter128Bit.matcher(s);
        return matcher128Bit.find();
    }

    public void sortIntoRespectiveIPTypes() {
        for (String s : tests) {
            if (myMatcher32Bit(s)) {
                bit32.add(s);
            } else if (myMatcher128Bit(s)) {
                bit128.add(s);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("32 bit IPs");
        for (String ip : bit32) {
            System.out.println("  " + ip);
        }

        System.out.println("\n128 bit IPs");
        for (String ip : bit128) {
            System.out.println("  " + ip);
        }

        int count = 0;
        for (String ip : tests) {
            if (myMatcher32Bit(ip) == false && myMatcher128Bit(ip) == false) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count != 0) {
            System.out.println("\nDidn't match an IP format");
            for (String ip : tests) {
                if (myMatcher32Bit(ip) == false && myMatcher128Bit(
                        ip) == false) {
                    System.out.println("  " + ip);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void sort32BitIPs(List<String> bit32, List<String> newBit32) {
        List<BigInteger> bigInt32Bit = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        for (String ip : bit32) {
            String[] tempArray = ip.split("\\.");
            int i = 0;
            for (String s : tempArray) {
                if (s.equals("")) {
                    tempArray[i] = "0";
                }
                i++;
            }
            bigInt32Bit.add(convert32Bit(tempArray));
        }

        Collections.sort(bigInt32Bit);

        List<String> fixFormat = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String ip : bit32) {
            String[] fixArray = ip.split("\\.");
            int i = 0;
            for (String s : fixArray) {
                if (s.equals("")) {
                    fixArray[i] = "0";
                }
                i++;
            }

            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 4; i2++) {
                if (i2 < 3) {
                    try {
                        if (!fixArray[i2].equals("")) {
                            strBuilder.append(fixArray[i2] + ".");
                        } else {
                            strBuilder.append(".");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        strBuilder.append("0.");
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        strBuilder.append(fixArray[i2]);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        strBuilder.append("0");
                    }
                }
            }
            String newString = strBuilder.toString();
            fixFormat.add(newString);
            bit32 = fixFormat;
        }

        for (BigInteger finalValue : bigInt32Bit) {
            for (String ip : bit32) {
                String[] tempArray = ip.split("\\.");
                int i = 0;
                for (String s : tempArray) {
                    if (s.equals("")) {
                        tempArray[i] = "0";
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (finalValue.equals(convert32Bit(tempArray))) {
                    if (!newBit32.contains(ip)) {
                        String str = bit32.toString();
                        String findStr = ip;
                        int lastIndex = 0;
                        int count = 0;

                        while (lastIndex != -1) {

                            lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr, lastIndex);

                            if (lastIndex != -1) {
                                count++;
                                lastIndex += findStr.length();
                            }
                        }

                        for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
                            newBit32.add(ip);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    BigInteger convert32Bit(String[] array) {
        int[] tempArray = new int[array.length];
        List<BigInteger> tempBigIntList = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        int i = 0;
        for (String s : array) {
            int power = 4 - i;
            tempArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(s);
            String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[i]);
            BigInteger myBigInt = new BigInteger(string);
            BigInteger num2 = myBigInt.multiply(new BigInteger("256").pow(
                    power));
            tempBigIntList.add(num2);
            i++;
        }
        BigInteger bigInt32Bit = new BigInteger("0");
        for (BigInteger bI : tempBigIntList) {
            bigInt32Bit = bigInt32Bit.add(bI);
        }
        return bigInt32Bit;
    }

    public void sort128BitIPs(List<String> bit128, List<String> newBit128) {
        List<BigInteger> bigInt128Bit = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        for (String ip : bit128) {
            String[] tempArray = ip.split(":");
            int i = 0;
            for (String s : tempArray) {
                if (s.equals("")) {
                    tempArray[i] = "0";
                }
                i++;
            }
            bigInt128Bit.add(convert128Bit(tempArray));
        }

        Collections.sort(bigInt128Bit);

        for (BigInteger finalValue : bigInt128Bit) {
            for (String ip : bit128) {
                String[] tempArray = ip.split(":");
                int i = 0;
                for (String s : tempArray) {
                    if (s.equals("")) {
                        tempArray[i] = "0";
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (finalValue.equals(convert128Bit(tempArray))) {
                    if (!newBit128.contains(ip)) {
                        String str = bit128.toString();
                        String findStr = ip;
                        int lastIndex = 0;
                        int count = 0;

                        while (lastIndex != -1) {

                            lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr, lastIndex);

                            if (lastIndex != -1) {
                                count++;
                                lastIndex += findStr.length();
                            }
                        }

                        for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
                            newBit128.add(ip);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    BigInteger convert128Bit(String[] array) {
        int[] tempArray = new int[array.length];
        List<BigInteger> tempBigIntList = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        int i = 0;
        for (String s : array) {
            int power = 8 - i;
            tempArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(s, 16);
            String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[i]);
            BigInteger myBigInt = new BigInteger(string);
            BigInteger num2 = myBigInt.multiply(new BigInteger("65536").pow(
                    power));
            tempBigIntList.add(num2);
            i++;
        }
        BigInteger bigInt128Bit = new BigInteger("0");
        for (BigInteger bI : tempBigIntList) {
            bigInt128Bit = bigInt128Bit.add(bI);
        }
        return bigInt128Bit;
    }

    public void printInOrder(List<String> bit32, List<String> bit128) {
        System.out.println("\nSorted IPs");

        System.out.println("Sorted 32 bit IPs - Ascending");
        for (String ip : bit32) {
            System.out.println("  " + ip);
        }

        Collections.reverse(bit32);
        System.out.println("\nSorted 32 bit IPs - Descending");
        for (String ip : bit32) {
            System.out.println("  " + ip);
        }

        System.out.println("\nSorted 128 bit IPs - Ascending");
        for (String ip : bit128) {
            System.out.println("  " + ip);
        }

        Collections.reverse(bit128);
        System.out.println("\nSorted 128 bit IPs - Descending");
        for (String ip : bit128) {
            System.out.println("  " + ip);
        }
    }

    public void run(List<String> bit32, List<String> bit128,
            List<String> newBit32, List<String> newBit128) {
        sortIntoRespectiveIPTypes();
        sort32BitIPs(bit32, newBit32);
        sort128BitIPs(bit128, newBit128);
        printInOrder(newBit32, newBit128);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IPSort ipS = new IPSort();
        ipS.run(ipS.bit32, ipS.bit128, ipS.cleanBit32, ipS.cleanBit128);
    }

}
```

### OOPness

You have a lot of default level variables and methods. Instead, make them `private`.

---

Your code is not very OOP. Yes, I don't see `static` methods, but you are including the `test` parameters inside the class, which is just as bad. You also print in the class, which should be done outside. This all violates SRP (Single Responsibility Principle).

I suggest have a separate class for just sorting, and just testing. Think about:

- Is this class only doing what it is supposed to do?

  - Good answer: Yes!
  - Bad answer: Not really...
- Is this class doing too many things?

  - Good answer: No!
  - Bad answer: Yep...
- Is this class well-structured (i.e. inheritance-wise and method-wise)?

  - Good answer: Yes!
  - Bad answer: Not really...

Since that would take a while, I'll leave it up to you...